# What are android folders myrecord/acrosspromote?

Tags: applications, storage, motorola-moto-g

Moto G, android 4.4.4
What are the folder and its subfolder:  myrecord/acrosspromote/? which app creates them?
in the subfolder I have some weird files like cachedAcrossPromotespec.txt, in its text this file makes references to "u.best.sex". 
Must be publicity for a free app.

Comment: These are distinct folders and a single response may not satisfy all your queries. Please separate them into unique questions.

Comment: Whole tree is myrecord/acrosspromote/cachedAcrossPromotespec.txt